# Nginx & Yii2 solo con IP

Tags: php, yii2, nginx

Tengo un servidor VPS instalado un Ubuntu Server 14.04, como servidor web Nginx 1.9 y estoy por poner en producción un proyecto desarrollado Yii2. El servidor se accesa por IP publica y la configurado del nginx es la siguiente forma:

```
server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;

            root /var/vhosts/sac.local/rem;
            autoindex on;

            index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

            access_log /var/log/nginx/sac.access.log combined;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/sac.error.log;

            server_name _;

            location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            }

            location ~ \.php$ {
                   try_files $uri =404;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
                    include fastcgi_params;
            }

    }
```

He intentado agregar un location adicional con un alias para indicar la ruta del proyecto, pero no logro levantar el proyecto.

Básicamente necesito como agregar un configuración de tal manera que el proyecto sea accesado: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/v3

Alguna idea?

Comment: Te arroja algún error cuando accedes a la ruta? ejecuta este comando "sudo nano /var/log/nginx/error.log" y escríbe lo que muestra

Comment: @LuisAlbertoAguileraClarke en este momento al intentar accesar a la aplicación lo que me sale por browser es un 404 con la configuración que puse originalmente. Yii Framework provee configuraciones, en mi versión local me base en [esta configuración](https://gist.github.com/sergeyklay/c045185b77ad5fa44b55) pero no tengo problemas ya que tengo configurado mi /etc/hosts con un nombre de dominio.

Comment: @LuisAlbertoAguileraClarke el error log no da ningún mensaje

Comment: Hola @Ale. Deberías agregar la configuración que estás usando realmente, para poder ayudarte. Si tienes alguna preocupación por la confidencialidad de tu información inventa nombres. Pero pon la configuración actual, no la ideal.

Comment: porque en server name lo tienes así ?   "server_name _;" ?? yo lo agrego con localhost o la ip pública.. si es error 404 no es el servidor, es tu proyecto el que tiene dramas

Answer (score 1):

debieses tener un location así:

```
location /v3 {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

de tal forma que si calza la ruta con v3, intenta usar las $uri entregadas. 
Para extender un poco, al tener esto:

```
location ~ \.php$ [...]
```

le estás diciendo que cualquier ruta que termine en php sea ejecutada mediante lo definido dentro, es decir, por php-fpm.

Ahora si quisieras que tu ruta por defecto redirija a /v3, es otra cosa